# When can a celebrity be referred to by their surname only?

Tags: word-usage

**Mark Twain**'s case is straight-forward: it's a pseudonym, pronounced as if it were one word.

So is **Stendhal**, for that matter.

However, here's a list of folks who can be referred to by their surnames only, no problem:

**Einstein

Clinton**
**Bush** (even though there are three)
**Monet**
**Van Gogh**
**Verdi**
**Wagner**
**Hemingway**
**Nabokov**
**Balzac**
**Shaw**
**Shakespeare**
**Eisenhower**
**Tolstoy**
**Zola**
**Mussolini**
**Whistler** (the guy who painted his Mom)

On the other hand, if you say, "I read this story by **Poe**," someone is very likely to make absolutely sure by asking, "*Edgar Allan* Poe?" - as if there were other famous authors by that name.

The same goes for:

**William Faulkner**
**Frans Hals**
**John Singer Sargent** (any other famous painters by that name? And yet, go figure, there's always someone inclining his or her head politely and going, "*John Singer* Sargent?" No, Groucho Sargent.
**Kurt Vonnegut**
**Benedict Jumping Cumberbatch**
**Che Guevara**
**Susan Sarandon**

Now why is that?

Comment: It is an interesting question in its own right, and could stimulate some interesting discussion, but I see no way this can be answered objectively.

Comment: I think Faulkner belongs in the Einstein list.　And maybe Vonnegut.

Comment: I wonder if there are people who became well known in two different careers, but are known by different versions of their name in each case. With people not realizing they're the same person.

Comment: clinton?  thats two people

Comment: @Keltari: I'm trying to pretend that the one who wears skirts but would look more plausible in trousers doesn't exist. She's been insanely annoying all these years.

Comment: ... "Benedict Jumping Cumberbatch"?

Comment: @PressTilty: "Walk? Not bloody likely! I'm going in a taxi."

Comment: @Ricky: I think you just have acquaintances who enjoy showing off that they know the forenames of the person under discussion. If you say "I've just read a novel by Waugh" then *of course* a natural response is "Evelyn or Auberon?", because it's ambiguous. But if you talk about the painter "Sargent" and someone says "John Singer Sargent?" then they aren't in doubt so they're basically just "correcting" you to demonstrate their knowledge. Put them to the test: see if they know Michelangelo's and Rembrandt's *surnames* ;-)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Depends what you mean by "people not realising". It's hardly a secret, but for example the careers of Mark Wahlberg and Marky Mark are fairly distinct and there are probably a *few* people left in the world who'd recognise both names as celebrities but never made the connection. There are also people who've worked under not different versions of their name, but completely different names, with varying levels of knowledge among the general public that they're the same person.

Comment: @Ricky that does nothing to clarify my question

Comment: Some of your example aren't universally valid. Anyone somewhat familiar with US politics, but not following the primaries, is going to say "which one" when you talk about Clinton, and certainly Bush. It all depends on the context and what your audience knows.

Comment: Ricky, this is an interesting question but I don't think answerable sufficiently in a couple paragraphs. And it's not particularly restricted to English (maybe better at linguistics.se). Basically you're asking why there are idioms and abbreviations. I have an idea (appeal to laziness and entropy and such) but it needs a lot of theory and extended explanation to justify.

Answer (score 38):

There are a few flawed premises and irrelevancies in this question.  Twain being a pseudonym is irrelevant.  A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.  Twain being a surname is irrelevant. Remember Cher or Oprah?  Those are first names.  Even Twain being a celebrity is irrelevant.  Well almost.

What is important is the ability to say a name and have people know who you mean.  That ability to uniquely identify them from only one name depends on context.

If I say Poe, most people think Edgar Allan Poe without any need to make sure.  Unless I'm in a context where that's ambiguous.  Say I have a dog named Poe.  If I say, "Oh Poe is the best" in that context you can't be sure what I mean.

You are focusing on a particular context, celebrity.  I know of no celebrity with the name Poe other than Edgar Allan Poe.  Though I don't particularly read tabloids so I may be missing someone.  What makes sense to me might not make sense to others.  @RoaringFish does have a point here about this being subjective.

However, there is one very objective factor when it comes to the names of celebrities:  [The Screen Actors Guild](http://www.sagaftra.org).  They ensure that an actors name, in the context of acting, is unique.  It's one of the reasons so many actors have stage names that are different than the ones their parents gave them.  It's also why there is a J in Michael J. Fox.

Ofcourse, not every celebrity is in the Guild.  Not every screen actor is a celebrity.  It's not a perfect system.  Someone with the name Einstein might someday become a famous politician and the Guild wouldn't be able to do a thing about it.  Soon people would be asking questions like, "[Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_(disambiguation))?  You mean the physicist or the politician?"  It's called [disambiguation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disambiguation).  It's needed when there is [more than one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twain) obvious meaning.  It's why we have surnames in the first place.  Famous or not.

In the end there is no perfect objective assurance of uniqueness.  Any author or speaker must first make an attempt to uniquely identify the subject of discussion.  Afterwords they can shorten it like I have when mentioning "the guild". I've created a context where what that means is obvious by first introducing the guild.

Sometimes there is no good way to uniquely identify someone.  We have people who've done nothing wrong who can't use air travel because someone else with their name is on the no-fly list.

Celebrity itself can be thought of as the state of having been introduced to the public.  It's not binary though, some remain little known their whole career.  Even stars become obscure as the public's memory fades.  In politics they actually measure this in polls.  It's called [name recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_recognition).

So, when can a celebrity be referred to by their surname only?  When doing so makes your audience think of only one person.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to come up with an objective answer, but as Tolkien, Shakespeare, Van Gogh, Homer, Einstein were not screen actors is still looks very subjective to me.

Comment: @RoaringFish The point I took away from this answer, as emphasized by the specific example of the practice of The Screen Actors Guild, is that celebrity names are actively chosen - by the celebrity, or an organization, or the public in general - by their (at least contemporary) distinctiveness. Short of presenting empirical evidence, how much more objective can you get?

Comment: @talrnu ~ do you have anything more substantial than subjective speculation that the  use of Tolkien, Shakespeare, Van Gogh, Homer, and Einstein etc. was an active decision by.... somebody? Even if we accept that for the sake of argument, it is little more than reframing the question and declaring it an answer: "Why do some celebrities use their first name and others the last?" ~ "Because sometimes the first name is chosen, and other times the last..."

Comment: +1, but in my experience "Poe" with no a first name most often refers to [Nathan Poe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe's_law). ;-)

Comment: @ruakh good point.  The reality is that most cases there is no guaranteed unique identifier. Only ones that make it very likely that people will understand who you mean.  Oh and thanks for the "Good Answer" badge! :-)

Comment: Regarding disambiguation; some parent/child "celebrities" have been assigned generational qualifiers to distinguish them. So we have Pliny the Elder and his adopted son, Pliny the Younger. Later on William Pitt (1st Earl of Chatam) became known as Pitt the Elder, presumably after his son, Pitt the Younger also became Prime Minister. Perhaps future historians will refer to Bush the Elder and Bush the Younger. Would be better than _Dubya_, for sure.

Comment: @Owen And nowadays if you refer to someone as just _Pitt_, you’re much more likely to be referring to Brad than any of the ones you mentioned.

Comment: Best I can think of, off the top of my head, is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dontari_Poe

Comment: In the late 1990s, referring to "Poe" might have been understood as a reference to the singer known as "[Poe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe_%28singer%29)" (she used that one-word name as a stage name). She was quite popular for several years. There are also possible misunderstandings (in speech) with ex-Celtics forward [Leon Powe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leon_Powe) and Constitutional scholar [Lucas Powe](https://law.utexas.edu/faculty/powela/). So having a common name is at least one factor tending to discourage one-name identification. Machiavelli has it easier in that respect.

Answer (score 10):

This is actually really simple. You can refer to someone by their last name whenever two conditions are satisfied:

1. **There is no danger of confusion in the minds of your hearers**
2. Using just the last name conveys the amount of respect and formality that you intend.

The first of these is most important, and it is context dependent. For example an article about different American presidents can refer to "Kennedy" without any fear of confusion, even though there are plenty of other people called Kennedy in the world. If you are talking about physical thermodynamics you can refer to [Boyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Boyle) without worrying that you will be confused with [someone else called Boyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Boyle).

For the second, it's generally considered less respectful to use only a surname.

Comment: *Everyone laughed when Susan Boyle entered the laboratory. Well, she'd been laughed at before.*

Answer (score 7):

It could well just be what popular culture names things. "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet...". "'When I use a word,' Humpty Dumpty said in rather a scornful tone, 'it means just what I choose it to mean - neither more nor less.'" Our shared culture labels things with names, and some of those things happen to be people. There is a conventional form of this name, that on one's birth registration, but that's hardly the only form.

In the UK in the last few years, it has become common for celebrities to be described only by their first name. Most people in the UK would know who you meant by Delia, Jamie, Hugh, and I don't think Nigella has a surname any more! Some are last-name-only, like Corbyn. Some are both, like David Attenborough.

I think it's just culture and convention, something that catches on. If there is a possibility of confusion, more words are used for disambiguation. Calling David Attenborough either "David" or "Attenborough" would be confusing. But calling Dawkins "Dawkins" is not.

Comment: That last one is upsetting. Is he being deified? Darwin the all-giver and Sir Richard his prophet? Wow.

Comment: Attenborough might have referred to his sibling Richard. I wonder after the film maker/ actor's death if that ambiguity has been removed.

Comment: Whether Attenborough is ambiguous depends on the context. If you  are talking about nature documentaries, you can just say Attenborough, and we know you mean David. If you are talking about film directors, you can just say Attenborough, and we will know you mean Richard. Context is all.

Comment: @Ricky, Dawkins is not being deified, any more than Churchill or Hitler, Stalin or Roosevelt, Montgomery or Rommel, Eisenhower or Mao, Nasser or Eden, Arafat or Netanyahu.

Comment: @Ben I would argue that DA is more famous to the general public than RA, who made some great films, and starred in some classics, but I belong to an older generation, and I love films. I wonder if anyone over 25 knows who RA was. I would guess that anyone who mentions the late director uses his full name. I might be wrong of course, I don't live in the UK.

Comment: If someone said Attenborough, most people I know (UK) would assume David. The expectation would be that if you meant his brother you'd say Richard Attenborough. Like if you meant a different Madonna or Jesus, you'd explicitly say "Jesus Javier" or "Madonna Smith". The point is that the "one name only" is assumed to be the most famous person, and anyone else requires clarification.

Comment: @Ricky what are you referring to with 'that last one', I see nothing about Darwin in this answer at all.

Comment: The case of Nigella is similar to Attenborough.

Answer (score 4):

In the company of most folks, if you reference "Bach", they will assume you're speaking of [Johann Sebastian Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Sebastian_Bach).  If, though, you are in the company of folks more educated about Classical Music, they may ask you to verify that, as two of his sons were also rather accomplished composers.  Personally, I have a preference for playing the compositions of [C. P. E. Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Philipp_Emanuel_Bach).

It's mostly a matter of how familiar your audience is with other folks of the same name.  Your best bet is to try to understand the scope of your audience's knowledge.  But don't be overly concerned.  If you miss the mark, they will likely ask you to specify exactly who you mean.

Comment: Or, of course, P. D. Q. Bach.

Comment: @BPete I had a chance to see Peter Schickele when he came to town some years ago.  Quite an entertaining event...

Answer (score 1):

The formula is as follows:

> Fame of celebrity among your intended audience * unusualness of name > required level of unambiguity

The importance of unusualness of name can be seen for example in the case of **Pablo Ruiz Picasso**. Both his name (Pablo) and his first (paternal) surname (Ruiz) are extremely common, hence he is known by his maternal surname.

There is also a tendency to use first names for female celebrities and surnames for male celebrities (sexist though it may be, this seems to be the default usage by commentators on tennis tournaments in the UK.) This rule is often overruled by the previous one (for example **Kardashian** when referring to Kim, with other members of her family referred to by their first names.)

Finally, there is the question of what to do with celebrities with very common names. Here an abbreviation is often used: **J-Lo** or **K-Fed** (Actually Federline is not particularly common, it just seems that at 3 syllables it is longer than the attention span of the average tabloid journalist / reader.)

Comment: I think you may be onto something so far as the formula goes. Some of the examples are faulty, though. Elvis was the fellow's Christian name, and he was a man. I don't remember hearing anyone referring to Azarenka as simply "Victoria." I'm one of the very few people in the world who have a very vague idea of who the Kardashians are. I know who J-Lo is (I may have even met her socially, I can't remember), but I had never heard of K-Fed until you mentioned him just now (please forgive me: I'm a Wagnerite, though, perhaps, not quite a perfect one).

Answer (score -1):

I think for everyone over a certain age, and with an IQ bigger than their hat size, "Che" is sufficient, as is "Cher", "Madonna", "Elvis", "Hillary", and probably dozens of others if we really thought about it.

But to answer your specific question, some people are known by their full name (Mark Twain, Edgar Allen Poe, Susan B Anthony, Martin Luther King Jr), and many others are well known by their surname only (or nickname or first name).  Arnold Parlmer was universally known as "Arnie", but Arnold Schwarzenegger did not achieve the same "Arnie" status. It's the way it is.

And a lot of this stuff depends on how old you are, what your interests are, and what country you live in.

Comment: One of your examples strikes me: I doubt I've ever (or at least often, consciously) heard *Martin Luther King* with generational qualifier. Only the last name *King* would probably leave many confused except within strict context (or people might confuse King's speach with the movie *The King's speach*). The most problematic shortcut would be the firstname *Martin Luther* as that is in itself the full name of another "celebrity".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - I generally find that Americans will tend more often (but not always) to qualify MLK with "Jr". Most of the rest of the world tends not to.

Comment: @JonStory Probably because all of us grew up in a town with a street bearing his full name, title and suffix included. In my case: "Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr. Drive"

Comment: That would make sense

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Oh, but I thought you'd celebrate "Martin Luther King day"?

Comment: Some of these are context dependent. In the UK if you said "Hillary" and people had to guess who you were talking about, they would probably guess Sir Edmund Hillary. I believe my IQ is larger than my hat size.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's true. However on the media coverage that day he will be called "Dr. King" or "Martin Luther King, Jr." or "Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr" or even "MLK" (far less formally). I suspect again ultimately this comes down to context: [Martin Luther King, Sr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King,_Sr.) was also a major player in the Civil Rights Movement, and many are still old enough to remember that.

Comment: @abligh - Precisely. I also assume Cargill is talking about Che Chesterman, the virgin Mary, and Elvis Costello; but we may never know for sure.

Comment: You touch on a good point. "Arnold" or "Arnie" is ambiguous, but "Ah-nold" (said with a bad Austrian accent) is unmistakably Schwarzenegger. It's all about context, familiarity and convention.